# Parallelize Rails Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am experimenting with using minitests `parallelize_me!` function to run my tests in parallel. I am trying to get just two empty tests to pass:

```
class Example < ActiveSupport::TestCase                                  

  parallelize_me! 

  test 'create' do                                               
    p 'create'                                                                      
  end                                                                           

  test 'invalid' do                                                       
    p 'invalid'                                                                                          
  end                                                                           
end
```

I've commented out all my fixtures and I'm only trying to run these two tests in parallel. It keeps throwing errors like this:

```
Error:
Example#test_invalid:
RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant <ClassName>
```

The class name changes each time to a different class.  I guess it's trying to load the app each time in parallel and getting confused or something.  How can I use this feature?  Are there some good resources available on the subject?

App is on `ruby-2.4.0`, `Rails 5.0.1`

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this?

Comment: @JimmyBaker I gave up on it for the time being :(.  Let me know if you find any good resources on it!

Comment: You need to eager load the app since multiple threads are trying to access the same module at the same time. The easiest way to do this is by adding `config.eager_load = true` to the `config/environments/test.rb` file.